# i am fetching a data from sentienl1 rtc using python in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, sentinel1

The code in jupyter environment
so I am able to run it in jupyter notebook in local env. and its taking ages to do but still showing in progress, when i try to do the same in colab or sage-maker its throwing issue like

ValueError: Failed to auto-guess CRS/resolution.Below is the error

```
    ValueError
    Cell In[20], line 3
    1 ## Get Sentinel-1-RTC Data
    Traceback (most recent call last)
    2 assests = ['vh', 'vv']
    ----> 3 train_band_values=crop_yield_data.progress_apply (lambda x: get_sentinel_data(x['Longitude'], x['Latitude'],x['Season (SA = Summer Autumn, WS= Winter Spring)'], assests), axis=1)
    4 vh = [x[0] for x in train_band_values]
    5 vv = [x[1] for x in train_band_values]
    ---> 3 train_band_values=crop_yield_data.progress_apply (lambda x: get_sentinel_data(x['Longitude'], x['Latitude'],x['Season (SA = Summer Autumn, WS= Winter Spring)'], assests), axis=1)
    4 vh = [x[e] for x in train_band_values] 5 vv = [x[1] for x in train_band_values]
    Cell In[19], line 32, in get_sentinel_data(longitude, latitude, season, assests)
    29 item items[0] =
    30 items.reverse()
    ---> 32 data = stac_load([items [1]], bands-bands_of_interest, patch_url=pc.sign, bbox-bbox_of_interest).isel (time=0)
    34 for item in items:
    35 data = stac_load( [item], bands-bands_of_interest, patch_url=pc.sign, bbox=bbox_of_interest).isel (time=0)
    File/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.18/site-packages/odc/stac/_load.py:494, in load(items, bands, groupby, resampling, dtype, chunks, pool, crs, resolution, anchor, geobox, bbox, lon, lat, x, y, like, geopolygon, progress, fail_on_error, stac_cfg, patch_url, preserve_original_order, **kw)
    476 gbox = output_geobox(
    477     _parsed,
    478     bands=bands,
    (...)
    490     y=y,
    491 )
    493 if gbox is None:
    --> 494 raise ValueError("Failed to auto-guess CRS/resolution.")
    496 if chunks is not None:
    497     chunk_shape = resolve_chunk_shape(gbox, chunks)
    ValueError: Failed to auto-guess CRS/resolution.
```

I already tried running in local but its taking ages

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). You can *edit* your question and replace the images with properly formatted text. See: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i rectified that @PawelKam

Answer (score 0):

Provide crs and resolution paramaeters in your stac_load method.
See examples below:
xx = odc.stac.load(...crs="EPSG:3857",resolution=10)
yy = odc.stac.load(...crs="EPSG:4326",resolution=0.00009009)